# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google.LuaLoader

Tags: android, coronasdk

I was putting a final touch to a game for iOS and Android in Corona yesterday.

Everything worked fine. Specifically the Google Play Game Services.

But then I updated the corona SDK I was using. Compiled fine on the simulator.
Build for Android and tried it on an android device and BAM ! 
The Google Play Game Service library is crashing the app.

I did not change a thing. I'm using SDK Build: 2013.2100

```
02-28 12:04:08.232: W/System.err(8088): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google.LuaLoader
02-28 12:04:08.232: W/System.err(8088):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-28 12:04:08.232: W/System.err(8088):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
02-28 12:04:08.232: W/System.err(8088):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
02-28 12:04:08.232: W/System.err(8088):     at com.ansca.corona.NativeToJavaBridge.callLoadClass(NativeToJavaBridge.java:375)
02-28 12:04:08.232: W/System.err(8088):     at com.ansca.corona.JavaToNativeShim.nativeResize(Native Method)
02-28 12:04:08.232: W/System.err(8088):     at com.ansca.corona.JavaToNativeShim.resize(JavaToNativeShim.java:317)
02-28 12:04:08.232: W/System.err(8088):     at com.ansca.corona.graphics.opengl.CoronaGLSurfaceView$CoronaRenderer.onSurfaceChanged(CoronaGLSurfaceView.java:358)
02-28 12:04:08.237: W/System.err(8088):     at com.ansca.corona.graphics.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1611)
02-28 12:04:08.237: W/System.err(8088):     at com.ansca.corona.graphics.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1377)
02-28 12:04:08.237: W/System.err(8088): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CoronaProvider/gameNetwork/google/LuaLoader
02-28 12:04:08.237: W/System.err(8088):     ... 9 more
02-28 12:04:08.237: W/System.err(8088): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google.LuaLoader" on path: /data/app/com.kayenko.bringbackjustinbieber-2.apk
02-28 12:04:08.237: W/System.err(8088):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
02-28 12:04:08.237: W/System.err(8088):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-28 12:04:08.237: W/System.err(8088):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-28 12:04:08.237: W/System.err(8088):     ... 9 more
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: System fails to find `CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google.LuaLoader`. Have you added the lib that contains `LuaLoader` to the build path?

Comment: Nikola, thanks for this comment. But this is Corona we're talking about. The libs are added by the framework. Or so I thought ! If you are familiar with corona could you post an answer explaining how to go about adding this library to a Corona project ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it !!!

I don't know why it happened in the first place, but then when trying different things, I moved and used a few different samples of code to include the GPGS in the build.settings file.

I ended up with :

```
android =
{
    googlePlayGamesAppId = "1006262955359", 

plugins =
    {
        -- key is the name passed to Lua's 'require()'
        ["CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google"] =
        {
            -- required
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
        },
    }, 
},
```

Instead of

```
android =
{
    googlePlayGamesAppId = "1006262955359",

},
plugins =
    {
        -- key is the name passed to Lua's 'require()'
        ["CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google"] =
        {
            -- required
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
            supportedPlatforms = { android = true }
        },


    },
```

The first one does make sense to me, that's why I never questioned it.

Now, on for the live posting on appstores :D